# problema con imagenes en vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Tengo un metodo hecho para generar un QR a partir de un texto:

```
Private Function QR() As String
   generarCodigoQR.QRCodeEncodeMode = Codec.QRCodeEncoder.ENCODE_MODE.BYTE
   generarCodigoQR.QRCodeScale = 12
   generarCodigoQR.QRCodeVersion = 0
   mensaje = "Hola, como te va?"
   imagen = generarCodigoQR.Encode(mensaje)
   Return MetodosBD.De_Imagen_A_Byte(imagen).ToString
End Function
```

el metodo `MetodosBD.De_Imagen_A_Byte(imagen)` retorna un Byte():

```
Public Function De_Imagen_A_Byte(ByVal Imagen As Image) As Byte()
   Using Stream1 As New MemoryStream
      Imagen.Save(Stream1, Imagen.RawFormat)
      Return Stream1.GetBuffer()
   End Using
End Function
```

pero cuando la funcion QR() llama a ese metodo me tira el error :
System.ArgumentNullException: 'El valor no puede ser nulo.
Nombre del parámetro: encoder'.

Comment: No veo en el código cuando inicializas `generarCodigoQR`. Puede que antes de
`generarCodigoQR.QRCodeEncodeMode = Codec.QRCodeEncoder.ENCODE_MODE.BYTE`
falte 
`QRCodeEncoder generarCodigoQR = new QRCodeEncoder(); `

Comment: Ya esta inicializado.